# Java SE android AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

```
package my.home.page;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private AsyncTask<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject> result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            JSONObject toSend = new JSONObject();
            toSend.put("id", "2151");

            JSONTransmitter transmitter = new JSONTransmitter();
            result=transmitter.execute(new JSONObject[] {toSend});

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public class JSONTransmitter extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject> {

        String url = "Some url";

        @Override
        public JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... data) {
            JSONObject json = data[0];
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 100000);

            JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            try {
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                post.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
                post.setEntity(se);

                HttpResponse response;
                response = client.execute(post);
                String resFromServer = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                jsonResponse=new JSONObject(resFromServer);
                Log.i("Response from server", jsonResponse.getString("EventId"));

            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}

            return jsonResponse;
        }

    }

}
```

how i can return jsonResponse in class MainActivity ?
i try :
void and call void
.get
etc
Pls help me !)////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare jsonResponse as a classmember in your activity then you don't need to return it .

or you can use post execute of AsyncTask to use response of doinbackgournd

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private AsyncTask<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject> result;
     JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try {
        JSONObject toSend = new JSONObject();
        toSend.put("id", "2151");

        JSONTransmitter transmitter = new JSONTransmitter();
        result=transmitter.execute(new JSONObject[] {toSend});

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public class JSONTransmitter extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject> {

    String url = "Some url";

    @Override
    public JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... data) {
        JSONObject json = data[0];
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 100000);
        JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        try {
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            post.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            post.setEntity(se);

            HttpResponse response;
            response = client.execute(post);
            String resFromServer = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            jsonResponse=new JSONObject(resFromServer);
            Log.i("Response from server", jsonResponse.getString("EventId"));

        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}

        return jsonResponse;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonResponse) {
    // do whatever you want to do  with jsonResponse

    }
}

}
```

Comment: dont work, application error

Comment: I have just added onpostexecute in your code , it should work

Comment: So how send it to MainActivity class?

Comment: Declare jsonResponse as a classmember in your activity , then use that same object in doinbackgound .

in post execute you can call the method which is updating the UI or where you want to use your json response

Comment: Can you please show me how show jsonResponse in  Toast.makeText?

Comment: @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonResponse) {

    Toast.makeText(ctx, "JSON Response"+jsonResponse.toString(),    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

Comment: Your's activityname.this. for example if your activity name is MainActivity then call MainActivity.this in place of ctx

Comment: You best!) now it show me but i still have no idea how do this from MainActivity class, how i can call void function or what?